# GAE: Slow delayed requests

Tags: java, jquery, google-app-engine

I have created a search bar on GAE similar to facebook that shows you 
names and pictures as you type into a search bar.  e.g. typing jo 
would bring up a drop down of "John Smith" and "Michael Jordan".  This 
works really well on the development server, and even works really 
well in production, when the user searches immediately after loading 
the page.  If I wait on the page, say 30 seconds to a min.  Then try 
and use the search bar, it takes a very long time to show the 
results.  Sometimes as long as 15 seconds, when it used to be 
immediate.  Can someone explain what is going on here.  Is there any 
way I can keep this request hot?  Also, if I search for jo then wait, get the results, delete jo and then type in another search, my results are shown immediately.  This makes me think that something is shutting down if not kept active.

My search bar implements the JQuery 
autocomplete bar and uses Jquery ajax gets to fetch the results.

Comment: What do your admin console logs show for those requests?

Comment: my bet is that your query on the backend is slow and when you get the result immediately is just because JQuery autocomplete caches the previous results.

Comment: @systempuntoout that is not the case.  My requests usually return in under 100ms.  It seems that my requests are causing new instances to be created, even though there is no latency on the instance.

Comment: @Lumpy I see, sounds weird. Have you tried to call the url path directly without using jquery?Does it really cost 15 secs to have a response in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it actually starts new instances. Go to Dashboard and in Chart section in combo select "Instances" instead of requests / second.

Comment: It seems that a dynamic instance is created for my request.  Even though there are 3 resident instances available with no latency.  Could this dynamic instance be killed immediately then another must be created?

Comment: Do you have "threadsafe" option turned on? By default GAE does not allow parallel requests. You need to turn it on. Theoretically GAE should not need to start new instances for new requests if it is multithreaded. See last section here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens because if your application has less traffic, then the GAE "warms up" by starting a new JVM and that takes a few seconds.

More [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#What_Is_A_Loading_Request) about the "Loading Request".

The workaround to this is to use the [Always On](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Always_On) mode for your application. Note that this is a premium feature.

Comment: I have always on turned on for this application

Comment: @Lumpy -- Can you check in your logs to see if a new process is getting started after you remain idle for a little bit? That will give you a hint as what's going on.

Comment: If a new instance is being created, is there anything I can do to fix the problem?